# How to remove the blank in the start of the paragraph that after a figure?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am writing my thesis, and I want my paragraphs work like: every paragraph has no blank in front, but different paragraph has one blank line. Then I choose to put "\vspace{8pt}\" at the end of the paragraph.
Most of time it works well:

[image]

The problem occurs when I insert a figure after the paragraph, and because of the layout of latex, it put this figure to another place(which is good), but the paragraph next will have a blank I don't need. What should I do to remove this blank? Thank you very much!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should almost never need to use `\vspace` within the document and never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph. There is no paragraph break in the code you show, remove `\vspace{8pt}\\ ` and replace by a blank line which marks a paragraph break.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. would you please tell me which code I should use is better to break a paragraph, and can get the format I need?

Comment: It is hard to answer your question as you have provided no code and only hinted at your desired format. But whatever the format the markup for a paragraph should just be a blank line, whether you have vertical space or horizontal indentation at the start of a paragraph should be a global property best set by the class (or using package such as parskip)

Comment: Usually the spacing between paragraphs is set by \parskip and the indentation by \parindnet.  For example, \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

Comment: Note that the space circled is not a paragraph indentation it is spurious white space from ends of lines in the source file caused by the bad `\\ ` markup preventing TeX's normal behaviour of discarding space at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand it fully. I have to use something like \\ or other code to tell latex that here is the end of a paragraph, right? Then what code should I use to replace the \\? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @user3324592 a blank line signifies end of paragraph never use `\\ ` for that, in fact use of `\\ ` outside of tables and other alignments is almost always incorrect.

Comment: When I put this code at my setting, the blank still exist. Do I need to add other code, or other package should I input in advance? @JohnKormylo

Comment: Are you writing this in LyX, as the tag suggests? (I'm assuming no.)

Comment: Yes, I am not. I have to put a tag for this question, 'latex' 'blank' and 'layout' are all not allowed. I have to post this question first, right :) @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got what you mean. Thanks to all the people here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space shown is an inter-word space, normally TeX drops spaces after a line break, but in this case the bad markup `\vspace{8pt}\\` has defeated that mechanism so the ends of line around `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` are causing white space in the output.

To mark a paragraph break in the source use a blank line never use `\\` for that.